# REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY changed to REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISPLAY

Tags: abap, alv

I'm having this problem. I'm calling a ALV report via `SUBMIT`command. This report calls `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISLAY` but when called, it shows a list like in `REUSE_ALV_LIST_DISLAY`. What are the possibles clauses?

Comment: Are you sure you execute both variants with the same user?

Comment: How do you populate itab for your grid? Do you use call transaction or BAPI?

Comment: I'm calling a ALV Report where I populate my itab by selections on DB. I think that the solution is use a `call transaction` with correct usage of option `NOIBINPT`

Comment: That's what I wanted to say. My assumption about BAPI seems to be true.

Answer (score -2):

When you use the SUBMIT sentence, program is executed in background, and ALV grids can't be processed in background mode, only ALV list are allowed.

Comment: It is wrong, indeed. Calling report in background using `SUBMIT` is done with clause `VIA JOB`, which is only a _special case_ of `SUBMIT`, but not essential feature.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly, the SUBMIT statement implicit call the report as a job, that's why the output is a LIST instead of a GRID.